# SQL: Summing time when the time field is char type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to move data from a table in one db to another. Everything is going fine except getting a total travel time from the travel time field which is set as a char(6) in H:MM format. I need to take the travel time for each stop in the route (given by dispatch number) for the given day (given by session date) and total it in a new field for that route.

Below is what I'm trying to do (Summing the char field of course wont work)

```
SELECT 
    [session_date], [dispatch_number], [stop_number], 
    [scheduled_arrival], [route_start], [customer_id],
    [distance], [travel_time], [service_time],
    [driver],
    (SELECT SUM([travel_time])
     FROM [exampleDB]
     WHERE [dispatch_number] = [dispatch_number]
       AND [session_date] = [session_date]) AS total_drive_time
FROM 
    [exampleDB]
```

I would greatly appreciate any help, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can write this without the correlated subquery using window functions:

```
select e.*,
       sum(travel_time) over (partition by dispatch_number, session_date) as total_drivetime
from exampleDB;
```

Of course, this doesn't fix the problem -- which is adding up varchars.  You can convert it to a time and then to minutes:

```
select e.*,
       sum(datediff(minute, '00:00', convert(time, travel_time))) over
           (partition by dispatch_number, session_date
           ) as total_drivetime_min
from exampleDB;
```

If minutes is sufficient, then this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, with some edits to fit the task it is up and running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help

```
Select Cast(DateAdd(MS,Sum(DateDiff(MS,'00:00:00.000',Cast([travel_time] as Time))),'00:00:00.000') as Time)
 From  [exampleDB]
 Where [dispatch_number]=[dispatch_number]
   and [session_date]=[session_date]) AS total_drive_time
```

To see a quick sample,

```
Declare @YourTable table (TimeString varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('6:30'),
('1:30')

Select Cast(DateAdd(MS,Sum(DateDiff(MS,'00:00:00.000',Cast(TimeString as Time))),'00:00:00.000') as Time)
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
08:00:00.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need your result also as HH:MM ,then try out with the below query.

```
;WITH cte_1 AS
(
    SELECT [dispatch_number],[session_date], SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', [travel_time]+':00'))total_drive_timeInMin 
    FROM dbo.[exampleDB] 
    GROUP BY [dispatch_number],[session_date]
)
SELECT e.[session_date]
  ,e.[dispatch_number]
  ,[stop_number]
  ,[scheduled_arrival]
  ,[route_start]
  ,[customer_id]
  ,[distance]
  ,[travel_time]
  ,[service_time]
  ,[driver]
  , RTRIM(total_drive_timeInMin/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(total_drive_timeInMin%60),2) total_drive_timeIn
FROM cte_1 c
 JOIN [exampleDB] e ON c.[dispatch_number]=e.[dispatch_number]
    AND c.[session_date]=e.[session_date]
```